# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in

Tags: php, mysql

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in 
/home/addictiv/public_html/AddictiveRP/Online/lib/katniss/mod.DB.php on line 95
```

This is mod.DB.php

```
class DB
{
    static $db = null;
    static $queries = 0;
    static $ms = 0;

    //
    // Connect to a PDO database
    //
    static function Connect( $connectstr, $username, $password, $persistant = false, $throwerror = true, $debug = false )
    {
        DEBUG::Msg( "Connecting to database", 'db' );

        $time = microtime( true );

        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => $persistant
        );

        try 
        {
            DB::$db = @new PDO( $connectstr, $username, $password, $options );

            if( $debug )
                DB::$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        } 
        catch ( exception $e )
        {
            DEBUG::Msg( "Connection Failed!", 'db' );

            if ( $throwerror )
                DEBUG::Error( array( 'error' => "Failed to connect", 'message' => $e->getMessage() ), 'DB' );

            return false;
        }

        DB::$ms +=  microtime( true ) - $time;

        DEBUG::Msg( "Connected!", 'db' );

        return true;
    }

    //
    // Throws an error if the database isn't ready
    //
    static function Check()
    {
        if ( !DB::$db )
            DEBUG::Error( array( 'error' => "No Connection" ), 'DB' );
    }

    //
    // Prepared statement wrapper
    //
    static function Query( $str, $arry = null )
    {
        DB::Check();
        DB::$queries++;

        DEBUG::Msg( "Query Start:", 'db' );
        DEBUG::Msg( $str, 'db' );

        $time = microtime( true );

        $st = DB::$db->prepare( $str );       // Line 95 error

        if ( !$st )
            DEBUG::Error( array( 'error' => "Create Query Failed", 'query' => $str, 'array' => $arry, 'message' => DB::$db->errorInfo() ), 'DB' );

        if ( !$st->execute( $arry ) )
            DEBUG::Error( array( 'error' => "Query Failed", 'query' => $str, 'array' => $arry, 'message' => $st->errorInfo()), 'DB' );

        $result = $st->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );    

        DEBUG::Msg( "Done", 'db' );

        DB::$ms +=  microtime( true ) - $time;


        return $result;
    }

    static function QueryRow( $str, $arry = null ) { $ret = DB::Query( $str, $arry ); if ( $ret ) return reset( $ret ); }
    static function QueryValue( $str, $arry = null ) { $ret = DB::QueryRow( $str, $arry ); if ( $ret ) return reset( $ret ); }

    static function QueryUpdateCheck($str, $arry = null){
        DB::Check();
        DB::$queries++;

        DEBUG::Msg( "Query Start:", 'db' );
        DEBUG::Msg( $str, 'db' );

        $time = microtime( true );

        $st = DB::$db->prepare( $str );

        if ( !$st )
            DEBUG::Error( array( 'error' => "Create Query Failed", 'query' => $str, 'array' => $arry, 'message' => DB::$db->errorInfo() ), 'DB' );

        if ( !$st->execute( $arry ) )
            DEBUG::Error( array( 'error' => "Query Failed", 'query' => $str, 'array' => $arry, 'message' => $st->errorInfo()), 'DB' );

        $st;

        DEBUG::Msg( "Done", 'db' );

        DB::$ms +=  microtime( true ) - $time;

        return $st->rowCount();




    }

    //
    // Insert an array into the database. Returns the insert id
    //
    static function Insert( $table, $arry, $insert = "INSERT" ) 
    {       
        $keys       = array();
        $keys_val   = array();
        $values     = array();

        foreach ( $arry as $k => $v )
        {
            $keys[]             = $k;
            $keys_val[]         = ':'.$k;
            $values[':'.$k]     = $v;
        }

        $query = $insert . " INTO " . $table . " (".implode( ',', $keys ).") VALUES ( ".implode( ',', $keys_val )." )";


        DB::Check();
        DB::$queries++;

        DEBUG::Msg( "Insert Start: [".$query."]", 'db' );

        $time = microtime( true );

        $st = DB::$db->prepare( $query );

        if ( !$st )
            DEBUG::Error( array( 'error' => "Create Insert Failed", 'query' => $query, 'array' => $values, 'message' => DB::$db->errorInfo() ), 'DB' );

        if ( !$st->execute( $arry ) )
            DEBUG::Error( array( 'error' => "Insert Failed", 'query' => $query, 'array' => $values, 'message' => $st->errorInfo()), 'DB' );

        DEBUG::Msg( "Done", 'db' );

        DB::$ms +=  microtime( true ) - $time;

        return DB::$db->lastInsertId();
    }

    //
    // Like insert, but replaces the entry if it exists.
    //
    static function Replace( $table, $arry ) 
    {
        return DB::Insert( $table, $arry, 'REPLACE' );
    }

    //
    // Called when shutting down
    //
    static function OnShutdown()
    {
        DEBUG::Msg( "Database: ". DB::$queries . " queries (". round( DB::$ms, 3 ) . " seconds)", 'db'  );
    }

}
```

What it calls for:

```
<?php
                define('MySQLSet', true); // Change this to true once you've entered your MySQL settings below
                define('MySQLHost', ''); // The host of your MySQL database.
                define('MySQLDBName', ''); // The name of your MySQL database.
                define('MySQLDBUName', ''); // The username of your MySQL database;
                define('MySQLDBPassword', ''); // The password of the user.
                define('PAGEID', '2003'); // Your VXDonation page id.
                define('APIKEY', ''); // Your Steam API Key (For avatars and such)
                define('BaseURL', '/Online/'); // Where the system is installed relative to your root.
                define('CURSYMBOL', '$'); // The symbol of your real world currency. £ or $ or whatever.
                // For example, if you accessed the system by going to yoursite.com/donation/mydonation,
```

I'm not an expert at this at all so i have no idea what's wrong

Comment: which line is line 95?

Comment: Check that your connection succeeded. If it did, perhaps the query is failing. Generally I see that error when a query fails and I am attempting to fetch the data

Comment: $time = microtime( true );

        $st = DB::$db->prepare( $str );       // Line 95 error

        if ( !$st )
            DEBUG::Error( array( 'error' => "Create Query Failed", 'query' => $str, 'array' => $arry, 'message' => DB::$db->errorInfo() ), 'DB' );

Comment: I'm all new to PHP and SQL and i'm trying to learn, so how can i see if the conection succeeded? and if it didn't, what to do then?

Comment: So, the call to `DB::Check();` on line 87 is "ok" with the DB::$db instance but on line 95 it's not an object.... so, what is it? What is printed when you place `if ( !is_object(DB::$db) ) die('not an object: '.var_export(DB::$db, true));` right before the `$st = DB::$db->prepare` line?

Comment: Then the question is: What does `DEBUG::Error` do? Apperently it doesn't abort the script ;-)

Comment: `DB::$db = @new PDO( $connectstr, $username, $password, $options );` -- Don't do this.

Comment: Yeah, don't. But it doesn't make a difference concerning the question.

Comment: How are you calling that function?

Comment: I have no idea what it does, i'm completely new to this. It's an addon to gmod, so i thought i could experiment with it, but i can't get it to work at all xD

Comment: Looks like either Connect() hasn't been called or it failed.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3j8f6uhc84fvej9/AAAf8CoF0diApqszqLEgzyOFa?dl=0    Uploaded the files to dropbox

Comment: fixed. my MySQL hosting refused to connect, so i changed and voilâ!